# vb.net New header every time i click download and reload into datagridview

Tags: vb.net

i'm trying to download datagridview to a csv file but everytime it is downloaded, there is a new line of header in the csv file.

```
Dim oldFile As System.IO.FileInfo = New IO.FileInfo(filePath)
    oldFile.Delete()

    Dim headers = (From header As DataGridViewColumn In gridData.Columns.Cast(Of DataGridViewColumn)() _
          Select header.HeaderText).ToArray
    Dim rows = From row As DataGridViewRow In gridData.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)() _
               Where Not row.IsNewRow _
               Select Array.ConvertAll(row.Cells.Cast(Of DataGridViewCell).ToArray, Function(c) If(c.Value IsNot Nothing, c.Value.ToString, ""))
    Using sw As New IO.StreamWriter(filePath)
        sw.WriteLine(String.Join(",", headers))
        For Each r In rows
            sw.WriteLine(String.Join(",", r))
        Next
    End Using
    Process.Start(filePath)
```

[How it looks like in datagridview and in csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4NXK.png)

as you can see from the picture in the link, there is repeated header on csv.

This is my read csv code

```
Private Sub ReadCSV()

    gridData.Rows.Clear()
    Dim TextLine As String = ""
    Dim SplitLine() As String
    If System.IO.File.Exists(filePath) = True Then
        Using objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(filePath, Encoding.ASCII)
            Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
                TextLine = objReader.ReadLine()
                SplitLine = Split(TextLine, ",")
                gridData.Rows.Add(SplitLine)
            Loop
        End Using
    Else
        MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")
    End If
    gridData.Rows(0).Visible = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you (re-)loading the data from the CSV file and using it to fill the DataGridView? The problem is most likely in _that_ code, which you haven't included in the question. Otherwise, please [edit] the question and provide a [repro].

Comment: You still did not include the code you use to reload the data into the DGV. Anyway, you're probably not skipping the headers when you load the rows from the CSV file, so you end up adding them as a row in the DGV. So, do skip the headers row when reading from the CSV file.

Comment: @41686d6564 it did not add my row(0), it read the default column names i assign in DVG

Comment: Yes, you did. You just make it invisible. Instead of using a StreamReader, it would be much easier to do `For Each line in IO.File.ReadLines(filePath).Skip(1)`. Note, however, that I don't recommend parsing CSV data manually unless you're certain that your data is very simple (e.g., doesn't contain commas, double quotations, or EOL characters). Otherwise, you should probably use a CSV parsing library.